# passing a subquery result in IN clause of a query

Tags: mysql, subquery

I want to use the result returned by a sub query into the IN clause of the other query in mysql i want to do something like BULK COLLECT one do in oracle database but I guess nothing like that is available in mysql

For ex :

```
set @features := (select group_concat(apf.featureid ) from 
applicationpackagefeature apf ,
feature f,
applicationpackage ap,
applicationpackageapplication apa,
application a
where f.id = apf.featureid
and apf.applicationPackageId = ap.id
and apa.applicationPackageId = ap.id
and apa.applicationId = a.id
and a.platform = 'b'
and a.version = 'a'
and a.name = 'c');
```

I want to store the id's returned by this query and use it in three set set od delete statement though i have used group_concat but it is not working

```
delete from applicationpackagefeature where featureid in (
    @features 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achive this using [Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) in MySQL:

```
SET @query = CONCAT('delete from applicationpackagefeature where featureid in (
',@features,')');

PREPARE stmt FROM @query; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```